# How to store DropDownListfor Text field value in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I am working on Umbraco Site,in Which I am using MVC4 and Umbraco 7.1.8. I have created one model, One Controller and One Partial View. 
I have one drop down list, When User select value in that drop down list, It should store that Text String. Instead of Text it is storing Index. Below is my code.

My Model :-

```
    public class PhoneType
    {
        public int typeid { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<PhoneType> PhonetypeOptions =
    new List<PhoneType>
    {
        new PhoneType {typeid = 0, Value = "Mobile"},
        new PhoneType {typeid = 1, Value = "Home"},
        new PhoneType {typeid = 2, Value = "Office"}
    };


    [Required, Display(Name = "Phone Number Type")]
    public string PhoneNumberType { get; set; }
```

My Partial View Html:-

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumberType)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PhoneNumberType, new            SelectList(Model.PhonetypeOptions,"typeid","Value",Model.PhonetypeOptions.First().typeid))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "Please Enter Email", new {@class = "error"})
        </div>
```

My Controller Code:-

```
       member.getProperty("phoneNumberType").Value = model.PhoneNumberType;
```

Now When I submit form and check in database, the phonenumber type is Index but not the Text String.

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: So what did you expect, sending the id to you server is the common way

Comment: But when you store dropdown value it should be text string , but in database i am getting index.

Comment: How would the value help you what if you rename that, its the id you want if not then what is the purpose. And if you dont want the index put the value in both sides in your list

Comment: Ok let me try that.. I just started working in mvc. I am new bee So I found this example and I made according to that. Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Like I explained the comments it makes sense to insert the `id` in your database.

If you ever decide to rename a value, you will be in trouble.

If you really wanted to store the text value , simply repeat the value as an id.

```
public class PhoneType
{
    public string typeid { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<PhoneType> PhonetypeOptions =
new List<PhoneType>
{
    new PhoneType {typeid = "Mobile", Value = "Mobile"},
    new PhoneType {typeid = "Home", Value = "Home"},
    new PhoneType {typeid = "Office", Value = "Office"}
};
```

But again , it makes more sense to save it as an Id.

Comment: @rsuthar, Your can also use `SelectList(Model.PhonetypeOptions, "Value", "Value", ....` but as meda has stated why have an ID property if your not going to use it. Refer [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)